# dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "signal"

Tags: android-ndk

I am developing an Android app using NDK.

I have built OpenSSL as static libraries, libcrypto.a and libssl.a, which I linked with my custom C code.

When I try to load the library at runtime I get:
dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "signal"...

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Update:

This comes from libcrypto:

libcrypto.a:

```
00000000         *UND*  00000000 signal
```

In my .so I see:
libtest.so:

```
NEEDED               libc.so
...
00040240 <signal@plt>:
    40240:       e28fc601        add     ip, pc, #1048576        ; 0x100000
    40244:       e28cca80        add     ip, ip, #128, 20        ; 0x80000
    40248:       e5bcfd64        ldr     pc, [ip, #3428]!        ; 0xd64
```

So why is it complaining about "signal"?

Comment: You say you linked in static libraries? You don't use dlopen with static libs...

Comment: I linked the static libraries with my code and created a dynamic library .so. That's the one I load.

Comment: Use the ndk objdump to examine tbe .so and also figure out (possibly via recursive grep) where that symbol *should* be coming from.

Comment: How do you link your do so with the static libraries? Can you post your Android.mk?

Comment: Found the problem. I was using the new ndk64-r10 and of course was not working with my 32bit phone... I moved back to r9 (32bit) and everything works fine.