# Android NDK "dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol"

Tags: android-ndk

I'm trying to run an application that has C++ NDK compiled code but I'm getting the following exception:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "" referenced by "mylib.so"

I don't understand why I'm NOT getting the symbol that is missing: **symbol ""**

In other cases the missing symbol is visible like here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049603/dlopen-failed-cannot-locate-symbol-signal)

How can I find what is the missing symbol or what is the problem?

Thank you!!

Comment: Have you tried to copy this piece of output to file and analyze it with binary viewer? Maybe it is simply an unprintable character there between quotes?

Comment: Thank you! I will try that.

Comment: Finally I found the problem. When compiling I was not including all the .h files. Now I have an 'include' folder where i copy all the .h files with a .sh script.

Comment: Can you explain the solution a bit more? I'm now running into this problem compiling with clang. Is it because my own library is missing some symbols?

Comment: Yes. I fix it by having all the .h files in a 'include' folder. Now is all working.

Answer (score 1):

I met a mistake like this ：

ailed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol “lstat64”

It occurs in android 4.3 version, but it can run in the android6.0 version

This is my way to solve this problem：

NDK r10 dropped to NDK r9d, Then it ran up in android4.3 ！！！

Comment: Good job mate! See ya